# I am trying to figure out how to loop through my datatable. Any Suggestion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I do not want to bind it till its been looped through. What I have here is a csv file        uploaded to a gridview.I would like to loop through it before it is bound. Any Advice is    great.

```
   protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") +
                 FileUpload1.FileName);
            Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                 FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                 FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                 "Content type: " +
                 FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType + "<br><b>Uploaded Successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
    }



        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
        string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (string strHeader in headers)
            dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
        string[] data;
        while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
            dt.Rows.Add(data);
        csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;

        csvReaderGv.DataBind();


            }



    }
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing `foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)...`?

Comment: Do I put that before the csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;

        csvReaderGv.DataBind(); or after. Its confusion that is preventing me.

Comment: Yes, because your requirement is: _"I would like to loop through it before it is bound"_. This question is a little bit strange, isn't it?

Comment: Didn't think the question was strange. Sorry for that, I was really trying to be as clear as I could.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Loop through each row in the data table
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    // Loop through each column in row
    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++) 
    {
        // Do whatever you want here for each cell
    }
}
```

Here is what your code should look like:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + FileUpload1.FileName);
            Label1.Text = "File name: " +
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" + "Content type: " +
             FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType + "<br><b>Uploaded Successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
    }

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
    string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    foreach (string strHeader in headers)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
    }

    string[] data;
    while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(data);
    }

    // Loop through each row in the data table
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
    {
        // Loop through each column in row
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++) 
        {
            // Do whatever you want here for each cell
        }
    }

    csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;
    csvReaderGv.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: do I put it before or after binding where to put the foreach is what is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get your data;

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (string strHeader in headers)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
}       

string[] data;

while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(data);
}
```

Secondly, process your data what ever way you want;

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    // do what you want with it
}
```

Thirdly, when you have nothing else left to do with the data, bind it;

```
csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;
csvReaderGv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. You're asking how to loop a `DataTable` before you databind it. So what prevents you from simply doing:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // do something with the row and it's fields, e.g.
    string field1 = row.Field<string>(0);
    // or all columns_
    foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        string field = row.Field<string>(col);
    }
}
csvReaderGv.DataBind();
```

But i assume that you want to know what is the best way to loop a `DataTable` that is bound to an ASP.NET `GridView`. I suggest to use the `RowDataBound` which enables to access all rows in the table and also all rows in the `GridView`:

```
protected void csvReaderGv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string col1 = row.Field<string>(0);
        // set first cell in GridViewRow:
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = col1;
    }
}
```

This event is triggered for every row in the grid as soon as you `DataBind` it to it's `DataSource` anyway at this line:

```
 csvReaderGv.DataBind();
```

So it is the "cheapest" loop. 
Note that it's triggered only if you `DataBind` it, so not necessarily on every postback. If you need to access the `GridViewRows` on every postback(for example to create dynamic controls in the grid) you should use `RowCreated` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, will this also allow me to only have whatever columns I want show up.

Comment: @Jay: I must admit that i've not understood your comment. If you want to hide columns use `GridView.Columns[index].Visible = false;`. If you want to hide cells (or do something other like apply `CSS` or change `ColumnSpan`) use `e.Row.Cells[index].Visible=false;`.

Comment: Sorry, What I was asking was whether after I did the databind that I could use                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Card number" HeaderText="Card number" />.

Comment: That's aspx not codebehind. So you can use `BoundFields` or `TemplateFields` and access them (or modify their `Text`) from codebehind. But it's still not clear what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I got what I need from all the help, I much appreciated it.

Comment: @Jay: Consider to accept an answer then. Otherwise people will think that the question is still open.