# I am get a error I cannot figure out. object reference not set to an instance of an object. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: c#, object, data-binding

Here is my code, on line 144

```
peopleEntering.Add(new PersonEntered(personName, dateEntered, doorTypeEnum));
```

is where I get The error: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
WHY?

```
  protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName == string.Empty)
        {

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] FileExt = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('.');
            string FileEx = FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1];
            if (FileEx.ToLower() == "csv")
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(" " + FileUpload1.FileName));
            }
            else
            {

                return;
            }
        }
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
        string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (string strHeader in headers)
            dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
        string[] data;
        while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
            dt.Rows.Add(data);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string dateAndTime = row["Date and Time"].ToString();
            string personName = row["Description #2"].ToString();
            string doorType = row["Card number"].ToString();

            DateTime dateEntered = Convert.ToDateTime(dateAndTime);
            DoorType doorTypeEnum;

            bool personExists = false;
            foreach (object name in listboxOfNames.Items)
            {
                if (name.ToString() == personName)
                {
                    personExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!personExists)
            {
                listboxOfNames.Items.Add(personName);

            }
            switch (doorType)
            {
                case "A02 - Rear Entrance":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearEntranceDoor;
                    break;
                case "B12 - Exterior Main Floor Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorMainFloorDoor;
                    break;
                case "B12 - Interior Main Floor Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorMainFloorDoor;
                    break;
                case "C13 - Rear Break Room Door":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearBreakRoomDoor;
                    break;
                case "B02 - Exterior Basement Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor;
                    break;
                case "B02 - Interior Basement Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorBasementDoor;
                    break;
                case "D01 - Managed Services Main door":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesDoor;
                    break;
                case "D01 - Managed Services Big Door":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesBigDoor;
                    break;
                default:
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.None;
                    break;
            }
            peopleEntering.Add(new PersonEntered(personName, dateEntered, doorTypeEnum));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < peopleEntering.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
            string personName = peopleEntering[i].PersonName;
            if ( peopleEntering[i].DoorEntered == DoorType.RearEntranceDoor)
            {
                startDate = peopleEntering[i].DateOfEntry;
                for ( int j = i + 1; j < peopleEntering.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (peopleEntering[j].DoorEntered == DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor && peopleEntering[j].PersonName == personName)
                    {
                        endDate = peopleEntering[j].DateOfEntry;
                    }
                }

            }
            workSpans.Add(new WorkSpan(personName, startDate, endDate));

        }

        csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt.Rows;
        csvReaderGv.DataBind();
    }




            }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting your whole source code; post only relevant lines. And null reference exceptions are all the same... Just go in with a debugger and check why your object is null. `peopleEntering` is probably not initialized or set to null explicitly before that line, don't have the time to read _all_ that code.

Comment: Did you make sure to instantiate peopleEntering?  It seems like this may be the case.

Comment: You haven't shown the declaration or initialization of `peopleEntering`. I suspect you never give it a non-null value.

Comment: @Mani5556: I think you mean initialize rather than instantiate.

Comment: Looks like `peopleEntering` is `null`, but you didn't give us enough info to debug that. Open up Visual Studio, set a breakpoint, verify that `peopleEntering` is null, then trace back and understand why it's not being initialized properly.

Comment: You have lost me, please give a example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On that particular line the only possible source of a `NullReferenceException` is if `peopleEntering` is `null`.  Everything else in that statement is a new expression or a local / field read.  Looking at the posted method it appears this is a field vs. a local in the method.  Did you remember to initialize it to a non-null value (assuming type is `List<PersonEntered>`)

```
private List<PersonEntered> peopleEntering = new List<PersonEntered>();
```

Comment: The error could also come from the `PersonEntered` constructor; if it is marked with `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` or `[DebuggerStepThrough]` (not sure which at the moment), then the debugger would not stop inside the constructor, but at the call site, i.e. on that line.

Comment: @stakx that is very true. I was taking the OP on their word that this is where the exception actually occurred though.

Comment: @Jay, [just mark the answer that helped you the most as Accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if you solved your own problem [you can post your own answer to the question and mark that instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess since you are using ASP.NET (as seen in your [prev. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343467/i-am-trying-to-figure-out-how-to-loop-through-my-datatable-any-suggestion)):

I assume that you have initialized the `List` once, maybe with the `IsPostBack` check.

```
private List<PersonEntered> peopleEntering;

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         peopleEntering = GetPeropleEntering(); // a method that retrieves them from database
    }
}
```

In this case you either have to reload the list on every postback(remove the `IsPostBack` check) or you have to store it somewhere to retain it's state across postbacks. `Session` is one way. Remember that all variables (incl. all controls) are disposed at the end of a page's life-cycle.

Here are 8 others: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx